# Probability of two conditional events.

Tags: probability

How to find $P(A|B\cap C)$ if $P(A|B)$ and $P(A|C)$ are known?

Comment: how is $BC$ defined? $B \cup C$?

Comment: @Ant I mean BC happen simultaneously.

Comment: They both happen? Then it's $B \cap C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bayes' rule
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$$
And if $B$ and $C$ are independent
$$P(B\cap C|A)=P(B|A)P(C|A)$$
And applying Bayes' rule again:
$$P(A|B\cap C)=\frac{P(B\cap C|A)P(A)}{P(B\cap C)}$$